# Windows 10 closes many programs suddenly! (Chrome, Android Studio, etc)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, crash, filesystem-corruption, android-studio

Latest version of Windows 10 closes many programs when I use it without giving any error. For example when I play online chess, it closes Google chrome amid of my turn, or when I use Android Studio it close it sometimes. As I figure out It closes Google chrome many times when I try to copy some text from web. I don't know what exactly causes this problem.

My windows 10 is up to date. I've tried `sfc /scannow` in `cmd` and it find some corrupted files but after restarting the machine the problem remain.

I am not sure but is that possible non-compatible Graphic driver causes this problem?

System configuration: `CPU: Core i5-3570 3.4 GHz` `Graphic: AMD Radeon HD 7470` `RAM: 4GB DDR3 + 4GB DDR3L` `Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2, Build 19044.2006`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Latest version of Windows 10 closes many programs when I use it
> without giving any error

This is not normal and does not happen on my Windows 10 or 11 machines.

You ran SFC.

**(A)** Before running SFC, you should run DISM. So:

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

**(B)** If that does not fix the problem, run basic Windows 10 Repair using Keep Everything.

> Go to the Windows Media Creation Link
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(C)** If all above fails and nothing works, back up everything and reinstall Windows.

Make sure you do not have legacy, out of date, or non-compliant software installed as that may cause what you have.

Also remember that Windows 10 will build proper partitions including UEFI

**Followup Note and Strategy:**

Assuming you need to install Windows again, use the following guide:

1. Only use Windows to install (not another operating system).
2. Allow Windows to delete all partitions and create the 3 it needs: UEFI, Recovery, and main system.
3. Install Windows 10 as it wishes to be installed.
4. Once running, install the latest version of the Office Suite you use, Adobe Reader, modern printer.
5. Run the Manufacturer's Driver Update App to update any drivers not done in the main Windows install.
6. Install the latest version of Chrome

Stop now and ascertain that Windows 10 does not close programs when you use tem without giving any error.

Office suite, Edge, Chrome and Adobe Reader should not crash and printer should work.

Now install your other software, latest version, and check for errors.

Stop when or if you get the error you got and ascertain why.

Do this until all your software is installed (one item at a time) and checked.

Comment: Regard to (C): I've installed current windows two days ago. Why I need to reinstall it again?

Comment: You can remove legacy apps and try the repair install after removing legacy apps.  What you describe has never happened to me on Windows 10. Windows Repair install will also update needed drivers.  Some legacy software is probably causing this. I added legacy and out of date software to my answer

Comment: I also noted the need to uninstall non-compliant software.

Comment: When I tried to install Win 10, it messed up my boot options. For some reasons I booted using Ubuntu live then converted MBR to GPT using it and this removed all of my files. After many trial and error I installed Win 10 finally.

Comment: Windows 10 builds proper partitions as part of proper installation

Comment: I think overall I have answered your question including refinements how you used it.

Comment: Result of first command: `[=====                      10.0%                          ]`
`[==========================100.0%==========================]`
`The operation completed successfully.` Is that 10% OK?

Comment: Yes.  That is fine.

Comment: `Beginning verification phase of system scan.`
`Verification 100% complete.`

`Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: That also is correct. You implied that your system is now running properly. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: NO, same problem happened again for Android Studio!

Comment: Try uninstalling non-Windows 10 software

Comment: You meant software like Android studio and chrome?

Comment: yes . Windows 10 works fine, so you must have software installed that is not working with it

Comment: I posted an installation strategy for you to follow. Windows 10 works fine.